# Passing database name as a parameter in sp_executesql to be replaced in the query

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute a SQL statement joining tables from a different database. I would like to know if it is possbile in any way to replace the database name passed as parameter through sp_executesql?

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT
              A.* FROM TableA A
              INNER JOIN @dbName..TableB B ON A.C1 = B.C1
              WHERE B.C2 = @ptr',N'@BillingRunID int,@AccountID int,@dbName nvarchar(4000)',@ptr=1001,@dbName=N'Student'
```

The problem I am having is that I have the query in a .net project and it is called using sp_executesql during other process because of which the SQL can't be moved to the database as a proc or any other means. Is there any way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't parametrise an object name, it *must* be injected **securely**. You could achieve this like so:

```sql
DECLARE @dbname sysname, --Obviously this'll be assigned somewhere
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT A.*' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.Table A' + @CRLF +
           N'     INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) + N'.dbo.TableB B On A.C1 = B.C1' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE B.C2 = @ptr;';
--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
--Oddly, only @ptr is in your script, but it isn't defined in the second parameter.
--I therefore don't know what data type it needs to be.
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@prt {Your Datatype}', @ptr;
```